# Javascript/Jquery: Show a hidden div based on a Radio box select

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm doing is building a form, where when you select one answer a bunch of new questions pop up.

This is my working code:

```
$(".appliedWorked").click(function(){
   if($(this).val()==="appliedWorkedYes") 
      $(".appliedWorkedYesHide").show("fast"); 
   else 
      $(".appliedWorkedYesHide").hide("fast");
});
```

It works for only 1 class. I want to do this for many classes, so I thought I'd stick it into an array.

Here's my code for many classes but it's not showing when I hit yes on a radio box:

```
// storing an array of radio boxe class names
var radioBoxArray = new Array(
        "appliedWorkedYes",
        "workStudyYes",
        "workHistoryYes",
        "workWeekEndsYes",
        "cprYes",
        "aedYes",
        "aidYes",
        "wsiYes",
        "gaurdYes"
        );

// looping over the radio box array, too use the show feature of jquery
for(var j = 0; j < radioBoxArray.length; j++){
    // class name
    $("."+radioBoxArray[j]).click(function(){
        // value box
        if($(this).val()==='"+radioBoxArray[j]+"') 
            // show method
            $("."+radioBoxArray[j]+"Hide").show("fast"); 
        // hide else 
        else $("."+radioBoxArray[j]+"Hide").hide("fast");

    });

}
```

I think the issue is:

```
if($(this).val()==='"+radioBoxArray[j]+"')
```

Please help!

I've tried the following but will not show when I click on a box:

```
if($(this).val()=== radioBoxArray[j])

if($(this).val()=== String( radioBoxArray[j] ))

if($(this).val()==='"'+radioBoxArray[j]+'"')
```

Comment: why aren't you using `$(this).val()===radioBoxArray[j]` instead of `$(this).val()==='"+radioBoxArray[j]+"') `

Comment: What you get when you type `alert($(this).val()===radioBoxArray[j]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the syntax highlighting in your question. In

```
if($(this).val()==='"+radioBoxArray[j]+"')
```

the right-hand side of that test is just the string `'"+radioBoxArray[j]+"'`. Remove all those quotes.

```
if($(this).val() === radioBoxArray[j])
```

Other cleanup:

- Declare the array using array literal notation:

  ```
  var radioBoxArray = [
  "appliedWorkedYes",
  "workStudyYes",
  "workHistoryYes",
  "workWeekEndsYes",
  "cprYes",
  "aedYes",
  "aidYes",
  "wsiYes",
  "gaurdYes"];
  ```
- Save the `radioBoxArray.length` value in a local variable, otherwise it will be recomputed at every iteration. Also save the `radioBoxArray[j]` in a local variable (this also more efficient).

  ```
  var len = radioBoxArray.length,
      radio;
  for(var j = 0; j < len; j++){
      radio = radioBoxArray[j];
      // class name
      $("."+radio).click(function(){
          if($(this).val() === radio) $("."+radio+"Hide").show("fast");
          else $("."+radio+"Hide").hide("fast");
      });
  }
  ```
- Instead of using separate `show()` and `hide()` calls, use [`.toggle(showOrHide)`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle)

Final code can be cleaned up like so:

```
var radioBoxArray = [
    "appliedWorkedYes",
    "workStudyYes",
    "workHistoryYes",
    "workWeekEndsYes",
    "cprYes",
    "aedYes",
    "aidYes",
    "wsiYes",
    "gaurdYes"
    ],

    len = radioBoxArray.length,
    radio;

for (var j = 0; j < len; j++) {
    radio = radioBoxArray[j];
    // class name
    $("." + radio).click(function() {
        $("." + radio + "Hide").toggle($(this).val() === radio);
    });
}
```

Alternatively, you could use [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/):

```
var radioBoxArray = [
    "appliedWorkedYes",
    "workStudyYes",
    "workHistoryYes",
    "workWeekEndsYes",
    "cprYes",
    "aedYes",
    "aidYes",
    "wsiYes",
    "gaurdYes"
    ];

$.each(radioBoxArray, function(i, v) {
    $("." + v).click(function() {
        $("." + v+ "Hide").toggle($(this).val() === v);
    });
});
```

Comment: @Maatt your edit rocks. I appended 'slow' to toggle and got just what I wanted, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var radioBoxArray = [
        "appliedWorked",
        "workStudy",
        "workHistory",
        "workWeekEnds",
        "cpr",
        "aed",
        "aid",
        "wsi",
        "gaurd"
];

$.map(radioBoxArray, function(cls) {
   $('.' + cls).click(function() {
        // value box
        if($(this).val()===cls + 'Yes') 
            // show method
            $("."+cls+"YesHide").show("fast"); 
        // hide else 
        else $("."+cls+"YesHide").hide("fast");
   });
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I had to change to:    
   $('.' + cls+ 'Yes').click(function() {

Can you explain this and why it works vs my code?

Comment: so just swap $.map w/ $.each?

Comment: @Matt you're right architecturally, but I'm just annoyed of having the first index argument in `$.each` processing function - we don't care about it here.

Comment: @user494901 The difference between our codes is how we are using closures. Your `click` handler function "remembers" the `j` variable and actually its value will be the `radioBoxArray.length + 1` in every click handler - check it yourself with `console.debug(j)` - you'll be surprised :)

Comment: @user494901 when swapping `$.map` to `$.each` don't forget to also add another param to `function(cls)` => `function(i, cls)`

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(this).val()==='"+radioBoxArray[j]+"') is not correct
```

Try

```
if($(this).val()=== radioBoxArray[j])
```

or

```
if($(this).val()=== String( radioBoxArray[j] ))
```

Hope that helps

Comment: So there's absolutely no point in changing `radioBoxArray[j]` to `String( radioBoxArray[j] )`.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

`if($(this).val()==='"'+radioBoxArray[j]+'"')`